# Typeerror pushing javascript object key to new object

Tags: javascript, typeerror

I get a TypeError on one particular line (commented) when I run this code:
(I've only included this specific block of code, variables like chunk and count seen here are defined elsewhere).

```
//if semantic meaning found
if (msg.tmp.nlu.results.semantic_roles.length > 0) {

msg.tmp.nlu.results.semantic_roles.forEach( function (arrayItem){

    chunk[count].semantic.push( 
        {
        subject: arrayItem.subject.text,
        object: arrayItem.object.text, // TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"
        action: arrayItem.action.text,
        }   
    );
    score++;

});
```

}

This is the msg.tmp.nlu.results.semantic_roles array I run the forEach on:

```
[{
    "subject": {
        "text": "I"
    },
    "sentence": "I worked with the team to deploy a new marketing software application.",
    "object": {
        "text": "to deploy a new marketing software application",
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "new marketing software"
        }, {
            "text": "application"
        }]
    },
    "action": {
        "verb": {
            "text": "work",
            "tense": "past"
        },
        "text": "worked",
        "normalized": "work"
    }
}, {
    "subject": {
        "text": "I"
    },
    "sentence": "I worked with the team to deploy a new marketing software application.",
    "object": {
        "text": "a new marketing software application",
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "new marketing software"
        }, {
            "text": "application"
        }]
    },
    "action": {
        "verb": {
            "text": "deploy",
            "tense": "future"
        },
        "text": "to deploy",
        "normalized": "to deploy"
    }
}]
```

It's something to do with the arrayItem.object.text using the name 'object' but have no clue how to resolve it. Can anyone help?

Comment: What do you obtain if you do a console.log(arrayItem) just before the push?

Answer (score 0):

I cannot reproduce your problem, but I've tried to re-create code snippet based on your question. For me it should work correctly, without an `TypeError: Cannot read property 'text' of undefined"` error. Hopefuly you can use this *working code* to find and fix problem in yours.

```js
// simulates chunk[count].semantic array
const semantic = [];

// simulates semantic_roles array
const semantic_roles = [{
    "subject": {
        "text": "I"
    },
    "sentence": "I worked with the team to deploy a new marketing software application.",
    "object": {
        "text": "to deploy a new marketing software application",
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "new marketing software"
        }, {
            "text": "application"
        }]
    },
    "action": {
        "verb": {
            "text": "work",
            "tense": "past"
        },
        "text": "worked",
        "normalized": "work"
    }
}, {
    "subject": {
        "text": "I"
    },
    "sentence": "I worked with the team to deploy a new marketing software application.",
    "object": {
        "text": "a new marketing software application",
        "keywords": [{
            "text": "new marketing software"
        }, {
            "text": "application"
        }]
    },
    "action": {
        "verb": {
            "text": "deploy",
            "tense": "future"
        },
        "text": "to deploy",
        "normalized": "to deploy"
    }
}];

// Slightly changed forEach loop
semantic_roles.forEach( function (arrayItem){

    // Push items to the semantic array
    semantic.push( 
        {
        subject: arrayItem.subject.text,
        object: arrayItem.object.text,
        action: arrayItem.action.text,
        }   
    );

  // Log in console arrayItem.object.text for each item
  console.log('Text:', arrayItem.object.text);

});

//Log in console semantic_roles array
console.log('semantic_roles array:', semantic_roles); // 2 items

//Log in console semantic array
console.log('semantic array:', semantic); // 2 items
```

Comment: The issue I have found was that sometimes the semantic roles object sometimes came back from the api without the "object" object, hence the type error. Logging arrayItem showed this as @JuanMarcosArmella suggested.